# how to set height of BottomSheet full parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am trying to call BottomSheet using a[ndroid-support-library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) on Click of button. Its working fine but not taking full height. It reside below `AppBarLayout`. I didn't find any solution on [Android Documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

This is my Screen layout

[image]

[image]

Here is my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#5be5ad"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <!-- BottomSheet Layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
View bottomSheet;
private BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog;

private void initView(){
         /*
        Bottom Sheet Initialization
         */
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        // The View with the BottomSheetBehavior
        bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
//        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
                CommonMethods.getInstance().e("onStateChanged", "onStateChanged:" + newState);
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
                CommonMethods.getInstance().e("onSlide", "onSlide");
            }
        });

        behavior.setPeekHeight(100);

    }
```

Click Event Code:

```
@Override
    public void onShareClick() {
        if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
        if(mBottomSheetDialog==null){
            mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_bottomsheet, null);
            mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
        }

        mBottomSheetDialog.show();
        mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                mBottomSheetDialog = null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
behavior.setPeekHeight(100);
```

with

```
behavior.setPeekHeight(screenUtils.getHeight());
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ScreenUtils {

    Context ctx;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;

    public ScreenUtils(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);

    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return metrics.heightPixels;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return metrics.widthPixels;
    }

    public int getRealHeight() {
        return metrics.heightPixels / metrics.densityDpi;
    }

    public int getRealWidth() {
        return metrics.widthPixels / metrics.densityDpi;
    }

    public int getDensity() {
        return metrics.densityDpi;
    }

    public int getScale(int picWidth) {
        Display display
                = ((WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        Double val = new Double(width) / new Double(picWidth);
        val = val * 100d;
        return val.intValue();
    }
}
```

Using the above class we can set peek height like this.It will give the screen's maximum height.

```
 BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) contentView.getParent());
        ScreenUtils screenUtils=new ScreenUtils(getActivity());
        mBehavior.setPeekHeight(screenUtils.getHeight());
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a bit more how the class above and the code solves this problem?

Answer (score 2):

don't use `BottomSheetDialog` just use default behaviour like below(remove `BottomSheetDialog` code)

```
@Override
    public void onShareClick() {
    if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN || behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
           behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    } else {
           behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }
}
```

---

use `BottomSheet` layout to `match_parent`

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

</FrameLayout>
```

---

by above changes you have see BottomSheet with fullscreen

Comment: Its going below AppBarlayout, but it should overlap AppBarLayout

Comment: I had tried your code but its not covering Toolbar, its going behing Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this (Kotlin):

```
    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

Comment: not work if content is smaller than screen height

Answer (score 2):

For BottomSheetDialog you need to set fitContents to false

```
behavior.isFitToContents=false 
behavior.state=BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is repeated soooo many times in Stackoverflow and noone got the answer. But after some of experiment, I got the solution guys:

```
class SortProductBottomSheet : BaseBottomSheet() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_blablabla, container, false)-

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //THIS IS OUR LIFESAVER
        val dm = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
        val rect = dm.run { Rect(0, 0, heightPixels, widthPixels) }
        view.minimumHeight = rect.height()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java use `setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)` as follow

```
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext());
bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout);
bottomSheetDialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```